# How to prove the property of Lipschitz with regards to the Hessian matrix?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Function $f$ is convex and twice differentiable, $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz with constant $L$.

How to prove that
$\nabla^2 f(x) \preceq LI$ for all $x$？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$\nabla^2 f(x) \, v = \lim_{t \searrow0} \frac{\nabla f(x+t \, v) - f(x)}{t}.$$

Comment: Your first formula does not make sense since $\Delta x$ is a vector. You cannot devide by that. And it is also wrong, since the Hessian is not the first derivative of $f$, but of $\nabla f$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! May I ask why can't I use vector? If I change it to some other symbol would that be right? I am kinda confused about $t$ and $v$ that you wrote.

Comment: Because you cannot divide by a vector. In my formulation $t$ is a scalar and $v$ is a vector. I only divide by the scalar.

Comment: Thank you! My another question is, where exactly we get the identity matrix from the deduction?

Comment: If $A \, v \le L \, \|v\|$ for all $v$ (and if $A$ is symmetric), you get $A \preceq L \, I$.

Comment: Does $\nabla^2 f(x) \preceq LI$ also suggest $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz with constant L?

Comment: Together with convexity of $f$, the answer is yes. Otherwise, the negative eigenvalues of $\nabla^2 f(x)$ might not be bounded by $-L$.

Comment: Where do I need the property of convex function? And it seems that when we prove from Lipschitz it does not require the convex property of function $f$?

Comment: If you want to get Lipschitz of $\nabla f$ from $\nabla^2  f(x) \preceq L \, I$, you need convexity of $f$ to bound all eigenvalues via $0 \le \lambda_i \le L$. Otherwise, the eigenvalues could be arbitrarily negative. And yes, in the actual question, convexity is not needed.

Comment: Just wondering what would be wrong if some eigen value falls below 0? What I am thinking is the Lipschitz decides the upper bound and convexity (strong convexity) decides the lower bound of the eigen value, and there won't be a conflict or dependency between these two.

Comment: The scalar function $f(x) := -100 x^2$ satisfies $\nabla^2 f(x) \preceq 1 \, I$, but is not $1$-Lipschitz.